# Unable to click Sign in button of Microsoft Login in C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, staleelementreferenceexception

[image: Microsoft Login]

Trying to click Sign In button but getting "Stale element Exception error".

```
IWebElement email = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@name,'loginfmt')]"));
            IWebElement password = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@name,'passwd')]"));
            IWebElement signIn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@id,'idSIButton9')]"));
            IWebElement signInbtn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='idSIButton9']"));
            IWebElement signInbtn1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='submit']"));
        

        email.SendKeys("automate@outlook.com");
        email.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        password.SendKeys("Abc*123$");
        password.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
        signInbtn1.Click();
```

**Error:**

> OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : stale element
> reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: Clear you chrome cache  close browser  and reopen and check or open incognito window and check.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of getting the `StaleElementReferenceException` is that the driver have found the element, but the page refreshed by the moment, you try to interract it, so element state is stale.

Try to initialize the element `signInbtn1` after you fill the password field:

```
password.SendKeys("Abc*123$");
password.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
IWebElement signInbtn1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='submit']"));

signInbtn1.Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't using C# for the test script, but I'm calling the selenium driver via javascript (within a jest test) and was getting the same problem for that specific Login Modal you mentioned.

Looking at the HTML in dev tools, I found that there is a subtle issue when using the ID ("`idSIButton9"`) as the button element will change once the email has been entered in.
ie. The button element's value will change from 'Next' to "Sign in"

I found that using the id twice to identify the same button element results in the stale element issue.
So, for the second time round, I found the button element using the following xpath

```
"//input[@value='Sign in']"
```

This is much more specific than the id in this case.

Hope that helps.